# Why does a thin film of gold turn from pink/purple to green in reflected light when encased by glass?

Tags: optics, visible-light, glass

I am a glass artist working in the medium now for 25 years. I cannot figure this out. When I fume gold onto borosilicate glass, it appears pink/purple when not encased. If I encase the gold, it takes on a green color in reflected light.

I can thoroughly manipulate the glass, twisting and stretching and the green color stays. The amount of manipulation leads me to believe this isn’t a product of thin film interference, because the color is consistent while the gold layer surely cannot be after so much manipulation.

I read that Faraday obtained a thin green film of gold by applying stress to the gold. This leads me to believe the encasement is applying tensile strain to the gold film possibly.

I also fumed a solid rod with gold, and heated one side and stretched it at as cold a temperature I could to try and put tensile strain into the gold layer without annealing it with ambient heat left in the glass. It turned green in color when viewed in reflected light.

This in a way supported my theory that encasing the gold is applying some kind of strain being applied to the gold. I read that if a thin gold film is stressed it can turn green and will turn back to pink if annealed.

In my art work you can plainly see that the gold stays pink where not encased and is green where encased. This to me says the gold on the surface is able to relieve stress while the encased gold is not, but i do not know. For the past 25 years I have not been able to figure out why this happens.

Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to P.SE! I've taken the liberty of editing your question lightly, as very long paragraphs aren't very readable.

Comment: I should also add that pink/purple gold fume when encased can also take on a flat orange color if there a little more gold.